# how should i reference a php file from an external javascript file

Tags: php, javascript, url, filesystems, relative-path

So just a general question: if i have a file structure like this where i have an index page in the root folder along with a scripts folder, and in the scripts folder there are two scripts one a JS which is referenced in the index page, and the other PHP which is referenced from the js script:

root-folder:
--> index.html
--> scripts/
-----> myscript.js
-----> myscript.php

how should I access the php script from the js script using a relative url?

would it be: `./myscript.php` or `./scripts/myscript.php`

in other words is the relative url from the index file or the js file. thanks!

Comment: i believe ./myscript.php or just myscript.php. but it's funny, you could have figured that out yourself pretty quick.

Comment: The "./" can be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the javascript is operating in the scope of the page, not its physical location, the URL to the PHP would include /scripts/ in the path name.

Comment: okay, i had an idea that that is what was happening but i wasn't sure, thanks for the useful response